# Reading Json Form data golang

Tags: go, go-iris

I am sending form data in JSON & serialize format to golang server using ajax. I am not able to read those data.

I am using `kataras/iris` golang framework.

Below is my code -

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);

var Contact = {
    sendMessage: function() {
      return m.request({
          method: "POST",
          url: "/send/message",
          data: JSON.stringify(jQuery('#contact-form').serializeFormJSON()),
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-Token': 'token_here'
          }
      })
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Data looks like below, what is sent -->
"{\"first_name\":\"SDSDFSJ\",\"csrf.Token\":\"FjtWs7UFqC4mPlZU\",\"last_name\":\"KJDHKFSDJFH\",\"email\":\"DJFHKSDJFH@KJHFSF.COM\"}"
```

And I am trying to fetch the data from server using below code -

```
// Contact form
type Contact struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
}

contact := Contact{}
contact.FirstName = ctx.FormValue("first_name")
contact.LastName = ctx.FormValue("last_name")
contact.Email = ctx.FormValue("email")
ctx.Writef("%v", ctx.ReadForm(contact))
```

My all data is blank, How to grab the data? I am using https://github.com/kataras/iris golang framework.

Comment: Did you try adding the header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: no, I didn't add that, is it necessary to add one? I will just add one and test it out.

Comment: Usually form parameters require this header and parsing changes with that, if you use application/json, then it lets you auto-bind to structs, using the x-www-form-urlencoded sets the values as form, i.e: firstname=...&lastname=... and then it is parsed with FormValue / PostForm

Comment: my current `content-type` header value looks like this `content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: No change, still blank value.

Comment: check out the code sample here: https://github.com/kataras/iris/blob/master/_examples/http_request/read-json/main.go in MyHandler2 and just bind the request to your object, i.e.: var contact []Contact
 err := ctx.ReadJSON(&contact)

Comment: Got this weird error - `json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.Contact` , is it because of `content-type` value as - `application/json; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: try not "stringifying" your json, instead of JSON.stringify(jQuery('#contact-form').serializeFormJSON()) just do this: jQuery('#contact-form').serializeFormJSON()

Comment: wow, @unkgd you are the man, please post this as an answer, I will mark it as solved. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One the one hand, you are sending a JSON to the server, but when fetching the parameters you are fetching them as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", first, send the JSON parameters as JSON and not as string, remove the stringifying, i.e:

instead of:

```
JSON.stringify(jQuery('#contact-form').serializeFormJSON())
```

do:

```
jQuery('#contact-form').serializeFormJSON()
```

and in your Go file, bind it to your object:

```
var contact []Contact 
err := ctx.ReadJSON(&contact)
```

good luck :)